# ORA 12505 error for SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener

I have recently ran into a problem when trying to connect to my Database. The error is stating that it cant find the listener.

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

I read to post whats in the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora but when I try to open these files via windows explorer it tells me to choose a program to open it with, and then it doesnt open.

Can someone help me with this problem so I can get back to practicing coding please?

Comment: It isn't stating it can't find the listener, it's saying the listener is running but it doesn't recognise the SID you're supplying as part of the connection specification. The `tnsnames.ora` is only relevant if you're connecting using an alias. If it has worked before with the same values then it may be that the database isn't running - usually the DB will register with the listener when it starts. If it's (supposed to be) running on your PC then that should  be fairly easy to check. Maybe you've rebooted recently and it isn't set to start automatically, or it failed to start for some reason.

Comment: How do I start it up (if its not currently running) and check to see if its set to start automatically?

Comment: I don't do this on Windows, but [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24186/startrdb.htm#CHDDEEAF) may help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to view listener information in Windows is lsnrctl. 
Open a DOS command prompt on the server, not client.

```
lsnrctl status
```

View the other commands by

```
lsnrctl help
```

Also, the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files are text files. You can open those in notepad. The default location for the tnsnames.ora file on the client is:

```
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin
```

The default location for the listener.ora file on the server is:

```
ORACLE_HOME\network\admin
```